# How to get sorted output by id after selecting data from db in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, linq-to-entities

I have a list of `integers ids`, from table i need to select details only for those whose ids are in the list, `I have already done that` but i need that `data sorted same way as they were in the list Explaination below:`

```
List<int> SelectedUser = new List<int> { 26,1,22,27 };
List<ValidateDropDownBind> objValidateUserList = (from p in context.tblUser
                                                                  join q in context.tblTaskReportingAuthority on p.UserID equals q.UserID into gj
                                                                  from r in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                  where p.IsActive == true && p.CompanyID == CurrentAdminSession.CompanyID && SelectedUser.Contains(p.UserID)
                                                                  //orderby r.TaskReportingAuthorityID
                                                                  select new ValidateDropDownBind
                                                                  {
                                                                      value = p.UserID,
                                                                      name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName
                                                                  }).GroupBy(x => x.value, (key, group) => group.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Now, as i run this query i got the list of details from db but it is in `sorted form but i need to sort them by the form which they were` in the `list (SelectedUser).`

Comment: I have already removed Order by which was previously used but still i am facing the same issue out put is on the sorted form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not too pretty but you could use your first list and then select from the second list with `FirstOrDefault`.

The last `Where` is to be sure you do not include nulls if the first `SelectedUser` is not found in the `objValidateUserList` list.

```
var sortedList = SelectedUser.Select(
        sortedListUser => objValidateUserList.FirstOrDefault(nonSortedListUser => nonSortedListUser.value == sortedListUser))
        .Where(x => x != null);
```

Hope it helps!